# VU (dB) meters for surround 5.1 (PipeWire, KDE, Debian)

Tags: kde, vlc, pipewire, audio-volume, audacity

*I guess this is sort-of a software recommendation question, but if I post it there I think even less people will be familiar with this specific setup (5.1 surround, Debian 12, KDE and PipeWire)*

I recently upgraded from `PulseAudio` to `PipeWire` which enabled 5.1 on my setup surprisingly. I got a USB SoundBlaster that feeds *Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3)* (compressed 6-channel audio through TOSLINK optical) into my sound system. For the purposes of the question, the OS sees this as 6 individual channels, and I'm able to play for example multi-channel FLAC files in `VLC`, or even `Firefox`.

The built-in KDE sound applet in the System Tray as well as the System Settings > Sound allow me to individually control the volume of each sound channel, however only the applet shows a VU meter and it's in mono/stereo.

**Is there a program / plugin that can show the individual volumes of each sound channel, sort of like Audacity has its "Mixer Board" which displays the VU level of each individual track.**

I would be OK with any full fledged Gtk/Qt app, a KDE add-on, even a cli terminal app that shows the VU levels. Less preferable but even VLC add-on would at least do the job.

I recently started making multitrack mixes of different songs, and my own music I play on guitar into 5.1 mixes, but they are hard to balance just by listening, I want something visual as it plays. (`Audacity` shows these visually, but cannot output 5.1 audio during the mixing, only after it has been exported to FLAC and played with a different app like `VLC`).

I tried `Easy Effects` which is an amazing new app made for `PipeWire`, however they do not support multi-channel and do not plan on doing it as it would require a total rewrite (according to their Git/issues history).